# Create HTML table with header row and potentially missing cell values from array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I want to get the unique columns of each arrays inside array.

**My goal is to dynamically draw the columns depend on the array data.**

Example:

```
$arr = array(
        array('name' => 'Juan Dela Cruz', 'birthday' => '1988-07-11'),
        array('name' => 'Will Smith', 'birthday' => '1996-02-22', 'age' => '23'),
        array('name' => 'John Smith', 'birthday' => '1992-03-21', 'age' => '26', 'gender' => '<'),
    );
```

So the column output must be;
**name, birthday, age, gender.**

And the table output must be like this.

[image]

I tried array_keys and doesn't work as I want to.

```
array_keys($arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `array_keys` on the fully merged array to get all the keys, then forming an empty table row with those keys and merging each row of the array with that row for output:

```
$arr = array(
        array('name' => 'Juan Dela Cruz', 'birthday' => '1988-07-11'),
        array('name' => 'Will Smith', 'birthday' => '1996-02-22', 'age' => '23'),
        array('name' => 'John Smith', 'birthday' => '1992-03-21', 'age' => '26', 'gender' => 'M'),
    );
$keys = array_keys(array_merge(...$arr));
// header
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>', $keys) . '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
// body
// make an empty row
$empty = array_fill_keys($keys, '');
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', array_merge($empty, $a)) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Output:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>name</th><th>birthday</th><th>age</th><th>gender</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Juan Dela Cruz</td><td>1988-07-11</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Will Smith</td><td>1996-02-22</td><td>23</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>John Smith</td><td>1992-03-21</td><td>26</td><td>M</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OBJkC)

Comment: @mickmackusa don't know what I was thinking with the `array_combine(...)`. Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the answer.